# using cos function in plotting with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple text file composed of 8 columns and I read it with loadtxt function. I want to plot as y-axis column2-column5 and as x-axis column1-column4 divided by cos(column2-column5) so I put this commands

```
>>> y = data[:,2] - data[:,5]
>>> x = (data[:,1] - data[:,4])/cos(y)
and it gave this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cos' is not defined
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use numpy arrays. Then you can use element wise division. Additionally numpy provides all necessary math functions.

```
import numpy as np
d = np.asarray(data)
y = d[:,2] - d[:,5]
x = (d[:,1] - d[:,4])/np.cos(y)
```

Comment: Correct but since they are using `loadtxt` and 2D indexing I'm sure the variables already are numpy arrays.

Comment: Since it was not clear which `loadtxt` function he is using, `np.asarray` makes sure that we will have ndarrays. If it is already one, nothing happens.

Comment: It is tagged `matplotlib` so it's surely numpy loadtxt in question.  What else can you index like `data[:,2]`?  (not a rhetorical question)

Answer (score 0):

`cos` is in `math` module (as well as other mathematical libraries like `numpy` etc.)

```
import math
math.cos(3)
```

for `numpy`

```
import numpy
numpy.cos( np.array( [ [1,2], [3,4] ] ) )
```

Comment: -1 the argument is obviously an array, not a scalar, so `math.cos` won't work for their use case